# Should I get a bigger cage for my Lovebird?

Tags: birds, containment

so my family has had a single Lovebird for plenty of years now, but its cage is about 15" W x 15" L x 18" H. It wasn't until recently that I learned that the cage I bought might be bad for them, so I wanted to ask, should I get a bigger one? If so, what size would be recommended?

Comment: Do you have photos of the bird and cage?

Answer (score 1):

A bird's cage size can depend on the bird itself: your cage is on the small side, but if your bird spends a lot of time outside the cage & only uses the cage to sleep, it can suffice.

However, if your bird spends the majority of time in its cage, you need something bigger. [This website](http://www.bird-cage.com/how-to-select-a-bird-cage) contains a handy reference for the minimum cage size for a given species:

> **Species | Min. Cage Size | Bar Spacing**
>
> Finches | 18"x18"x30" | 1/4" to 1/2"
>
> Canaries | 18"x18"x24" | 1/4" to 1/2"
>
> Budgies | 18"x18"x24" | 1/2"
>
> Cockatiels | 20"x20"x24"  | 1/2" to 5/8"
>
> Lovebirds/Parrotlets  | 24"x24"x24    | 1/2"
>
> Ringneck Parakeets    24"x24"x36" 1/2" to 5/8"
>
> Conures/Poicephalus | 24"x24"x24"  | 5/8" to 3/4"
>
> Caiques/Pionus/Jardine's   | 24"x24"x36"   | 5/8" to 3/4"
>
> Amazons/Mini Macaws/Coffin's Cockatoos/African Greys | 34"x24"x36" | 3/4" to 1"
>
> Large Cockatoos | 36"x48"x48"  | 1" to 1.5"
>
> Large Macaws   | 36"x48"x60"   | 1" to 1.5"